# add time incements in a datetime format R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a datetime format that looks like:

"2021-06-21 12:12:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:12:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:12:00 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:12:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:00 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:14:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:00 UTC" etc

I want to add 10 sec increments to the data to look like:

"2021-06-21 12:12:20 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:12:30 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:12:40 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:12:50 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:10 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:13:20 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:30 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:13:40 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:13:50 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:00 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:10 UTC"
"2021-06-21 12:14:20 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:30 UTC" "2021-06-21 12:14:40 UTC" etc

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your actual data using `dput`, and explain exactly what you want to do with it. How are you deciding how many seconds to add to each date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%  
  mutate(times = times %m+% seconds(10 * row_number()))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  times              
  <dttm>             
1 2021-06-21 12:12:10
2 2021-06-21 12:12:20
3 2021-06-21 12:12:30
```

Comment: ive tried this one it adds 10 seconds to your data not 10 seconds increments, meanig 10,20,30,40,50 until you gent the next minute